# Select which fields to export in django-import-export

Tags: python, django, dynamic, field, django-import-export

I'm adding the django-import-export to the admin in my app.

One thing I wanted to do was to offer the possibility of selecting in the admin page of selecting which fields to export.

I searched for this topic but I only came across two questions with no answers.

Is it possible to add the possibility to dynamically choose which fields to export from the admin page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is achievable, but it is a little tricky.  Take a look at the [example application](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app), and get this working first.

1. Take a look at the [`BookAdmin`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/tests/core/admin.py#L23) implementation.
2. Create a subclass of [`ExportForm`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/import_export/forms.py#L39), which implements a form widget which can read the list of fields to export.
3. Add a `BookResource` constructor which can take a `form_fields` as a kwarg, and save this as an instance variable.
4. In `BookAdmin`, Override [`get_export_resource_kwargs()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/import_export/mixins.py#L56) methods to return the list of fields from the form.
5. Override [`get_export_fields()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/import_export/resources.py#L864) of `BookResource` to return the list of fields extracted from your form.
6. Finally, you'll have to override [`export_action()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/import_export/admin.py#L403) so that it creates an instance of your custom form.  (You actually only need to override the [line which instantiates the form](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/import_export/admin.py#L403) - there should be a `get_export_form()` method for this, so that the whole method doesn't need to be overridden. Feel free to submit a PR.)

Try this out with the example application before porting to your own app.

#### Example:

(based on [`admin.py`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/tests/core/admin.py))

```py
class BookResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def __init__(self, form_fields=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.form_fields = form_fields

    def get_export_fields(self):
        return [self.fields[f] for f in self.form_fields]


class BookExportForm(ExportForm):
    pass
    # Add your logic to read fields from the form


class BookAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'author', 'added')
    list_filter = ['categories', 'author']
    resource_class = BookResource

    def get_export_resource_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formats = self.get_export_formats()
        form = BookExportForm(formats, request.POST or None)
        # get list of fields from form (hard-coded to 'author' for example purposes)
        form_fields = ("author",)
        return {"form_fields": form_fields}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.
I tried it out. Now I just need to add checkboxes to the column headers and read which are checked, right?

Comment: yes, using checkboxes would be one way to do it

Comment: what if i want to send the file via mail instead of storing it?