# How to export the list of fields passed from the front end to excel through django-import-export

Tags: django-import-export

How to export the list of fields passed from the front end to excel through django-import-export
The fields from the front end are dynamic. The user chooses which fields are passed, and which fields we need to export
by export_key = request.query_params.get('export_key').split(',') Got the data passed by the front end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select which fields to export in django-import-export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67651313/select-which-fields-to-export-in-django-import-export)

Comment: Our needs are different. After the user selects the field, the front end passes it to me through get. What I get is a dictionary. How can I transform the fields in this dictionary into the fields in resources? I didn't do this. understand